# Hour difference between Linux and Windows from Java date.getHour()

Tags: java, windows, linux, getdate

I have some java code that parses a string and creates a Date object.  On Linux, everything works fine, but on Windows it continuously starts at 19:00:00 rather than 00:00:00.  Here is the code:

```
if(currTask != null) {
            if((m = p0.matcher(currTask)).matches()) {
                date = new Date(Long.valueOf(m.group(2)) - Long.valueOf(m.group(1)));
            }
            else if((m = p.matcher(currTask)).matches()) {
                date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - Long.valueOf(m.group(1)));
            }

            return padded(date.getHours())+":"+padded(date.getMinutes())+":"+padded(date.getSeconds());
        }
```

The returned value is the problem on Windows.  Is this some inconsistency with how one of Date's methods works on Windows as opposed to Linux?  Thanks for your help.

- Ken

Answer (score 5):

Check that your time zone is the same on both platforms... my guess is that they're not. (Print out `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()` to see what the default is.)

However, you shouldn't be using `Date.getHours()`/`getMinutes()`/`getSeconds()`/`getSeconds()` anyway; they're deprecated. You could use `Calendar`... or you could bite the bullet and use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which is a far superior date and time API.

What does your input look like and what's the result meant to be?

Comment: Yep. Most of Date's methods are deprecated, so I would not rely on them.

Answer (score 1):

The difference must be in your locale.  There are environment variables that affect this on Linux.  Let me guess: you're in EST (GMT-5)?